# i would like to change all my div in my html as well as my class name in css at the same time

Tags: html, css, notepad++

So i have created a horizontal navigation with a drop down menu, I've simply red what i saw and tried it myself. I've copied and pasted the html and css, I've changed the html in my lines of codes and it seems to work pretty well, now i would like to change the divs name to something more commun for mee since i am going to continue my html.

```css
header {
  border: 10px ridge blue
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="collegecss.css" />
  <title>college sainte marie </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="collegejvs.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="../premierepage.html"><img src="../saintemarie.png"></a>
    <h1>
      <titre>Bienvenue dans le site du Lycée Sainte-Marie</titre>
      <h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">accueil</a>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">information générale</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">inscription</a>


          <a href="#">historique</a>

          <a href="#">accéder au collège</a>

          <a href="#">horaires</a>

          <a href="#">règlement</a>

          <a href="#">tarifs</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#">calendrier</a>

      <a href="#">visite</a>

      <a href="#">pastorale</a>

      <a href="#">vie du collège</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i would like to change the div class : "container","dropdown","dropbtn" and "dropdown-container".And at the same time, it would change the css class name as well

any suggestion? i'm using notepad++ .

thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't. if you change one you have to change the other to match it. Otherwise you just break it.

Comment: I don't think this has naything to do with SO x) Anyway just copy paste everything in notepad and CTRL+F>replace> write the class you want to replace and the name of the new class > replace ALL

Comment: thank you @user5014677, it helps mee alot ^^

Comment: I think you can proceed to several adjustments to make your website more user-friendly : change your `.dropdown`'s background-color to `#333`, add capital letters to your menus and replace "Bienvenue dans" with "Bienvenue *sur*" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user5014677 said : 
I don't think this has naything to do with SO x) Anyway just copy paste everything in notepad and CTRL+F>replace> write the class you want to replace and the name of the new class > replace ALL

and it is right ^^ thank you @user5014677

Answer (score 0):

You can try ATOM or Sublime Text. its available for free download. Open your files in any of these Editors. make your selection-pattern with simple selection method and use "CTRL + D" to select similar text as selection-pattern in whole file. Multiple cursors will appear and you can change the text.

Or Simple FIND & REPLACE can be used if it is solving your problem.